# VSTS Task: Window machine file copy: system error 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to make a release from VSTS to a VM(running on AWS) that is running an IIS. For that I use three tasks.

1. Windows Machine File Copy
2. Manage IIS App
3. Deploy IIS App

Before the release I'm running a build pipeline that that gives me an artifact containing the web app (webapp.zip).
When I manually put it on the server I can run step 2 and 3 of my release and the application works. The problem I have is that I don't get the Windows Machine File Copy to work. It always throws an exception giving a 'System Error 53: The network path was not found'. Of course the machines are not domain joined, because I'm running my release on VSTS and need the files on a AWS VM. I tried to open port 445 (for file sharing) and made sure the user has rights for the destination path on the target machine. 
So my question is: How can I actually move the files from VSTS to the AWS VM if the two machines are not joined.

Comment: You can install a release agent on the machine, you can use an FTP copy task, *I tried to open port 445 (for file sharing)* FWIW I believe SMB generally needs ICMP, UDP 137, 138, TCP 139 and 445. You can also try a command line task that uses MsDeploy's remote deployment http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Deploying-to-remote-IIS-with-MsDeploy That's TCP 8172 by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [FTP Upload](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/ftp-upload) or [cURL upload](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/curl-upload-files) step/task instead.

Regarding how to create FTP site, you can refer to this article: [Creating a New FTP Site in IIS 7](https://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/creating-a-new-ftp-site-in-iis-7).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will give it a try.

Comment: This would also increase the surface area for hackers. Unless you have serious time to spend on security dont enable FTP on a public box.

Answer (score -1):

**Disclaimer**: this answer merely explains how to fulfill the requirements to use tasks of Windows Machine File Copy and Manage/Deploy IIS tasks.
Please always be concerned about security of your target hosts, its hardening and security assessment is absolutely necessary.

As noted in comments, you need to protect the channel of deployment from the outside world, here an high level example:

[image: Protect your deployment channel]

**Answer:**
in order to use the [*Windows Machine File Copy* task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy) you need to:

- on the target machine (the one running IIS) enable *File and Printer Sharing* running the following command from administrative command prompt:

  ```
  netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="File and Printer Sharing" new enable=yes
  ```
- assure that on the target machine PowerShell 4 or more recent is installed; the following executed from a PS command prompt prints the version installed on the local machine:

  ```
  PS> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion
  ```

  To get PowerShell 5 you could for example install [WMF 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395)
  ;
- on the target machine you must have installed .NET Framework 4.5 or more recent;

For the other two tasks (Manage/Deploy IIS Task), both require you to enable a WinRM HTTPS listener on the target machine. For development deployment scenario you could follow these steps:

- download the [ConfigureWinRM.ps1](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/PowerShellOnTargetMachines/ConfigureWinRM.ps1) PowerShell script at from the officaial VSTS Tasks GitHub repository;
- enable from an Administrative PowerShel command prompt the RemoteSigned PowerShell execution policy:

  ```
  PS> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
  ```
- run the script with the following arguments:

  ```
  PS> ConfigureWinRM.ps1 FQDN https
  ```

Note that FQDN is the complete domain name of your machine as it is reached by the VSTS task, e.g. myhostname.domain.example .
Note also that this script downloads two executables (*makecert.exe* and *winrmconf.cmd*) from Internet, so this machine must have Internet connection. Otherwise just download those two files, place them sibling to the script, comment out from the script the Download-Files invocation.

Now you have enabled a WinRM HTTPS listener with a self signed certificate. Remember to use the "Test Certificate" option (which ironically means to not test the certificate, better name would have been "Skip CA Check") for those two tasks.

In production deployment scenario you may want to use instead a certificate which is properly signed.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. Why is PS version 5 required?

Comment: Version 4 of PowerShell is required by the script underlying the task of Windows Machine File copy, if you have version 3 or earlier, usually I suggest to put version 5 instead, more recent, more features.

Comment: Will this not leave a machine on the internet open to hacking? I certainly would never enable this on a public box.

Comment: @MrHinsh i am certainly open to correct any mistake or blunder, could you please elaborate more about it? I am sure activating "file printer and sharing" would be potentially increase the surface of attacking on the machine, but if the target is internet facing the risk is always there, no protocol is safe. The server hardening and security assessment is absolutely necessary in any case. Let me know, thanks.

Comment: That's why the build and release agents for VSTS only Pull. They connect to the internet so you can have a server with the smallest surface area posible. No protocol is safe, but http on 80 is a hell of a lot easyer to secure than File and Print sharing.

Comment: Yes, i agree. I added an explicit note about the answer not dealing with security concerns, but merely explaining how to leverage the build tasks requested by the OP.

Answer (score -2):

Windows File Copy is designed to work on the same network and enabling it on the internet would open your server for hacking. It's designed for internal networks. FTP would also result in a significant security risk unless managed properly.

The easiest way to move forward would be to run an Agent on the VM in AWS that you want to release to. The agent will then download the artifacts to the AWS VM and run whatever tasks you need to install.

This allows you to run tasks on the local machine without opening it up to security risks.

If you had multiple machines that you need to manage in AWS you can easily create a local network that will allow your single agent to use Windows File Copy to push files to multiple VM's without risk.

Comment: What Í find strange is they the provide the task from VSTS. I would assume that if you run the task from VSTS it is newer on your local domain. It is a server running somewhere in a MS datacenter.

Comment: You don't run the task on VSTS, it runs on the Agent, which is wherever you need it to be. You can install the agent ob any Window or Linux server you like on any network.