# VSTS: Deploying to Azure based VM

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm setting up a test pipeline using VSTS and now I have my builds working using an Azure VM as a build agent, I want to also deploy to that machine. 
I've tried using the Windows File Copy and IIS deploy tasks but [understand this isn't a very good solution for security reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41527812/vsts-task-window-machine-file-copy-system-error-53), so wondered what the best task to use would be to get the build/release agent on the machine to copy the artefacts to the Azure based VM and deploy locally to its IIS install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you strongly reconsider not deploying your application to your build agent. This will make it extremely difficult to find issues due to missing DLLs or files because the build server has everything. I suggest either creating another VM to deploy to or leverage Azure's PaaS for web applications.

With all of that said, because you are working locally on the same VM, you can simply leverage the `Copy Files` task to move the files to where they need to be. To "deploy" the application, you can simply copy the output of the website to the IIS directory.

[image: VSTS Copy Files task]

Another option would be to create a PowerShell script that would setup, configure and deploy the application to the local machine. In which case, you could simply leverage the PowerShell task.

[image: VSTS PowerShell task]

Answer (score 1):

The source (**Get sources** section in build definition) will be download to build agent automatically during the build, so you don’t need to copy the files to that machine through Windows File Copy task, the simple workflow is that:

1. Add NuGet task to restore packages
2. Add Visual Studio Build task (MSBuild Arguments: `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true  /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\web.zip" /P:PackageTempRootDir=""`)
3. Add WinRM-IIS Web App Deployment task: (Web Deploy package: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\web.zip`)

As virusstorm said that you can copy files to other path on that machine through Copy Files task.

On the other hand, by default the artifact will be downloaded to the target machine if you are using release and you can consider [Deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/deployment-groups/) if the deployment machine is different with the build agent machine.